# Is there a way to disable React Native warnings in release mode?

Tags: react-native, security, react-native-ios, instabug

I'm working on a React Native app that uses Instabug bug reporting. In the logs we capture React logs and warnings such as this.

```
Instabug - REACT LOG: 2020-06-15 07:56:17.591 [info][tid:main][RCTBaseTextInputView.m:163] Native TextInput(some user input) is 5 events ahead of JS - try to make your JS faster.
```

The bug that caused this message has been fixed, but is there a way to disable these logs, or even this specific log, so we're never saving user input to Instabug in production? Having these warnings is valuable, so I'd prefer to hide as little as possible, while still preserving user privacy and security.

Comment: In production, warnings will not show

Comment: @TravisTay I'm aware the YellowBox warnings will not be displayed in app, but this warning was pulled directly from our production logs.